RAM detected but not used in Ubuntu
System:
cat /etc/os-release

PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.4 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy

Problem: I bought my computer with 8gb RAM. I installed another 8gb RAM in the empty slot. Ubuntu shows 16gb ram installed.

htop
enter image description here

lsmem

RANGE                                 SIZE  STATE REMOVABLE  BLOCK
0x0000000000000000-0x000000007fffffff   2G online       yes   0-15
0x0000000100000000-0x000000047fffffff  14G online       yes 32-143

Memory block size:       128M
Total online memory:      16G
Total offline memory:      0B


sudo lshw -class memory

*-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 3a
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 16GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2667 MHz (0,4 ns)
          product: CT8G4SFS8266.M8FD
          vendor: 859B
          physical id: 0
          serial: 25B3207D
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2667MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: [empty]
          physical id: 1
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM1
     *-bank:2
          description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2667 MHz (0,4 ns)
          vendor: Fujitsu
          physical id: 2
          serial: 8B5A0100
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2667MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:3
          description: [empty]
          physical id: 3
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM1


In the image above and from the code outputs I see that the RAM is 16GB, but when the computer is under pressure the RAM fills up to 7.9GB and then uses it from the swap.
When you look at the htop image, it shows around 50% full even though it uses 4GB. I was suspicious at this point and ran the stress command and the result was exactly as I expected. The CPU filled every core to 100%, and the RAM only filled 7.9 GB. It does not exceed 7.9GB. Why does it not use the second connected RAM even though it sees it?
stress --cpu 8 --io 4 --vm 4 --vm-bytes 1024M --timeout 8s

enter image description here
free -h
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15Gi       3,8Gi       3,0Gi       709Mi       8,7Gi        10Gi
Swap:          1,0Gi          0B       1,0Gi



I’m not an expert, but I can’t see anything here that tells me the swap is being used. Everything looks ok to me - it looks like the system sees 16GB but hasn’t used all of it. When the system is under stress, might not that just be that the processor is stressed but there remains plenty of ram?

Using SWAP while you have a lot of memory is a normal way for Ubuntu.
This system has also 16 GB RAM and at this moment top is showing this:

It is using 38% of RAM and 0.3% of Swap.
However if you feel like you want all of your ram to be used you can follow SwapFaq - Community Help Wiki
"Empty Swap
Even if you have lots of RAM and even if you have a low swappiness value, it is possible that your computer swaps. This can hurt the multitasking performance of your desktop system.
You can use the following script to get the swap manually back into RAM:

1.Place the script e.g. /usr/local/sbin:
gksudo gedit /usr/local/sbin/swap2ram.sh
1.Copy-paste the script into the file:

mem=$(LC_ALL=C free  | awk '/Mem:/ {print $4}')

swap=$(LC_ALL=C free | awk '/Swap:/ {print $3}')

if [ $mem -lt $swap ]; then

    echo "ERROR: not enough RAM to write swap back, nothing done" >&2
    exit 1
fi

swapoff -a &&
swapon -a

1.Save and close gedit
1.Make the script executable:
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/sbin/swap2ram.sh"
1.Execute:
sudo /usr/local/sbin/swap2ram.sh


I understood the reason for my question. When I looked at the output of the free -h command, I noticed that the buff/cache section was taking up a lot of space. For some reason, a significant portion of the 8 GB RAM was allocated to this section. After clearing it with the code below, I was able to increase the free space
sudo sync
sudo sysctl -w vm.drop_caches=3


